# Creating a simple hello world application using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am a java developer with 0 experience in java script. I am trying to learn angular and did tweak some projects to understand bit of angular. But I am definitely making some error in the basics. I am trying to run a hello world program in angular. I have an `index.html` and a controller in `app.js`. I am trying to call a function and show `Hello {{something}} !!`. I am unable to understand where I am going wrong. Please bear with me and clarify my mistake. here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chinmaydutta/QUB4f/1/).

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

var appController = function ($scope) {
   $scope.greeting = returnGreeting;
};

var returnGreeting = function($scope){
    return 'Hi '+$scope.name+ ' !!';
}
myAppModule.controller('appController', ['$scope',appController]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize `ng-app=""` so your app is not working, also you didn't define `$scope.name` so it returns undefined

Here is the working link: http://jsfiddle.net/QUB4f/8/

Spend time learning JavaScript, without the knowledge of language using complex framework is not a good idea

Comment: Thank you so much. I am aware of my extraordinarily dull java script skills. I appreciate your help.